# Struggling with TLS 1.2 implementation

Tags: python, https, tls1.2

So as a learning project I decided to implement https in python using TLS 1.2 and TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, everything went fine until the final encrypted handshake message, Using google chrome as a client it sent its part of the message but I wasn't able to decrypt it in a way it starts with a sequence of bytes that makes sense.

Here is what I did to try and test the decrypting of the encrypted handshake message
(The premaster appears to be correct as it starts with \x03\x03)

```
premaster_secret = pow(encrypted_premaster, d, n).to_bytes(256, "big")[-48:]

client_bytes = client_random.to_bytes(32, "big")
server_bytes = server_random.to_bytes(32, "big")

master_secret = prf(premaster_secret, b"master secret",  client_bytes + server_bytes, hashes.SHA256(), 48)

key_block = prf(master_secret, b"key expansion", server_bytes + client_bytes, hashes.SHA256(), 128)

client_write_MAC_key = key_block[0:32]
server_write_MAC_key = key_block[32:64]
client_write_key = key_block[64:96]
server_write_key = key_block[96:128]

IV = encrypted_handshake_message.to_bytes(64, "big")[0:16]

cipher = AES.new(server_write_key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
dec = cipher.decrypt(everything.to_bytes(64, "big")[16:])
print(unpad(dec, AES.block_size))
```

In the end the unpad function (From PyCryptodome) complains that the padding is incorrect and the message itself doesn't make much sense, I'll put it here incase I am stupid and it was correct all along (What I expect is something starting with 0x1400000C according to https://wiki.osdev.org/TLS_Handshake):
b'\x9f1k\xf6\xe9{B\xc0\x87\xfc\xd16z\xba\x06\xbd\x82L3%\xab\xf9\xdc\xe7\xcc\x9d\x0cs8F\x10\x08\xcf\x18n\xc1\xf4\xef\xee\x93\r\x06\xa4\xe2F8\x9c\x9d'